# Sponsor documents

Tags: visas, uk, paperwork

is it compulsory for the person inviting me to the UK to give me her bank statements and pay slips. She doesn’t want to give me the aforementioned two. The only thing she is willing to give me is the copy of her passport, invitation letter, employment letter and her utility bill. How helpful are these please

Comment: Is she sponsoring you (paying for your flights or accomodation) or are you just visiting her?

Comment: She is not paying for my flight ticket. She's only responsible for my accommodation and feeding.

Comment: If she is in rented accommodation she may need to prove that she is able to accommodate you eg permission from the landlord

Comment: Ok. But do I still need her bank statements and pay slips? She is my father's brother wife

Comment: Omo Naija those are enough for the visa application. My cousin got the same documents from my UK friend in February and successfully applied.

Comment: @The Zealot, are you a Nigerian. Pls can I contact you please?

Comment: No I am not. And this forum is meant for public discussion. All the answers to your UK visa questions can be found on here. UK visa questions are the most comprehensively addressed topic here and perhaps anywhere on the world wide web.

Comment: Thanks so much @the Zealot. So,  I should go ahead and apply with what she's willing to give.

Answer (score 2):

In offering to host you, the person would only need to provide an invitation that covers:

- they are willing to accommodate you during a specific time period (dates)
- their status in the UK (e.g., citizen, legal presence)
- the location of the property (address)
- that they have the right or permission to host (e.g., ownership, tenancy agreement, letter from landlord/housing authority)
- their contact information (phone, email)